# Building asp.net core docker image fail on WriteCodeFragment - Input string was not in correct format

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core 2.2 web api app. I'm trying to create a docker image, but getting error on building relase verion in docker. App run successfully when i type dotnet run, and everything work as excepted, also when i publish it to remote server it works. 
Output from docker build:

```
               „C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj” (element docelowy Build) (1:7) ->
               (element docelowy CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo) -> 
                 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018: Nastąpiło nieoczekiwane niepowodzenie zadania „WriteCodeFragment”. [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError() [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args) [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args) [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args) [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteCodeFragment.GenerateCodeCoreClr(String& extension) [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteCodeFragment.Execute() [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
               C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(134,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Users\ssobieszczanski\Downloads\ksiegowyBackend-master (1)\ksiegowyBackend-master\AuthWebApi\SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj]
```

I cant find place in code where it fails. Logs from docker returning only

```
  The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet build "SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

A dockerfile code:

```
  FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
  WORKDIR /app
  EXPOSE 80
  EXPOSE 443

  FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
  WORKDIR /src
  COPY ["AuthWebApi/SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj", "AuthWebApi/"]
  COPY ["SimpleAccountant.Logic/SimpleAccountant.Logic.csproj", 
  "SimpleAccountant.Logic/"]
  COPY ["SimpleAccountant.Common/SimpleAccountant.Common.csproj", 
  "SimpleAccountant.Common/"]
  COPY ["SimpleAccountant.Data/SimpleAccountant.Data.csproj", 
  "SimpleAccountant.Data/"]
  COPY ["SimpleAccountant.Models/SimpleAccountant.Models.csproj", 
  "SimpleAccountant.Models/"]
  COPY ["SimpleAccountant.Helpers/SimpleAccountant.Helpers.csproj", 
  "SimpleAccountant.Helpers/"]
  RUN dotnet restore "AuthWebApi/SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj"
  COPY . .
  WORKDIR "/src/AuthWebApi"
  RUN dotnet build "SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

  FROM build AS publish
  RUN dotnet publish "SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

  FROM base AS final
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY --from=publish /app .
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SimpleAccountant.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Do you have any path to files/folders in your app?

Comment: No i havent. I also commented all string builder parts.

Comment: That's the screen from docker action. https://imgur.com/a/uPuRHl3. This is huge application, and any logs not helping cause they showin same errors as in this screen, and i cant find a piece of code where it fails. Cause i dont know how to recreate it in another way.

Comment: Here is a code from docker file https://pastebin.com/CQiWtKqF. I've created it clickin right on webproject add -> new Docker Support.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information and do not show your code as a picture

Comment: try to move your project to folder without space like current "ksiegowyBackend-master (1)" and try again

Comment: Share us the content for `SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj`. Do you have any custom `WriteCodeFragment` in your csproj?

Comment: There was a problem inside SimpleAccountant.Api.csproj, i've opened it with text editor and found brackets inside my UserSecretsId. I removed them, and docker image build correct.  Thanks for your time and help.